# Configure Translation component in Symfony 2 to use gettext

Tags: symfony, internationalization, translation, gettext

Symfony 2 as version 2.1 supports gettext (MO and PO files).

I have following configuration (`app/config/config.yml`):

```
framework:
    translator:      { fallback: "en" }
    default_locale:  "fa_ir"
    ...
```

How can I configure to support for mo files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found without any configuration I can put `messages.fa_ir.mo` in `Resources/translations` directory of bundle and Symfony2 itself will find it...