# How to use Gettext (.mo/.po) files with Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, translation, gettext

I want to use `Gettext` for the translation of my website on `Symfony2`

In `../Resources/translations/` i have my translations files like that :

```
translations/en/LC_MESSAGES/en.mo
translations/en/LC_MESSAGES/en.po
translations/fr/LC_MESSAGES/fr.mo
translations/fr/LC_MESSAGES/fr.po
...
```

I already configured the default local variable with the help of `Symfony2 cookbook` to be french(fr) http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#the-locale-and-the-url

When i go to `app_dev.php/fr/hello/test`, my Hello World is in english. There is something else i need to configure?

Already tried this configuration : [Configure Translation component in Symfony 2 to use get text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218175/configure-translation-component-in-symfony-2-to-use-gettext)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few days of research, I finally found an answer. It's not the one that i was searching for, but it's a very good alternative.

I found this **Awesome Bundle** : https://github.com/LeaseWeb/LswGettextTranslationBundle

Very easy to put in place, i recommend you to use "routes" to change locales like that :

```
prefix:   /{_locale}/
    requirements:
        _locale: |fr|en|es|pt #All your locales "shortcuts"
```

Be sur to configure the Bundle to use locales shortcuts in `Lsw/GettextTranslationBundle/Resources/config/config.yml` like that :

```
parameters:
    gettext.locale_shortcuts:
        en: en_US
        fr: fr_FR
        pt: pt_PT
        es: es_ES
```

For all configurations, use the step by step bundle configurations (easy to use)

Answer (score 4):

Using Gettext (.mo/.po) files with Symfony is very simple and does not require any additional bundle.

The following is an example about how to use *.po files for translations.

First add the `default_locale` parameter in **parameters.yml**:

```
parameters:
    # ...
    default_locale: en_US
    # ...
```

Then enable the translator in **config.yml**:

```
framework:
    # ...
    translator:
            enabled: true
            fallbacks: ['%default_locale%']
            paths:
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/translations'
    # ...
```

And add the service to the services.yml file:

```
translation.loader.po:
    class: Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\PoFileLoader
    tags:
        - { name: translation.loader, alias: po }
```

Place your mo/po translation files under `app/Resources/translations` using the following structure:

`app/Resources/translations/messages.en.po`

`app/Resources/translations/messages.it.po`

`...`

Now from your controllers you can call:

`$this->get('translator')->trans('my.message.id');`

Comment: Works well in Symfony 4, thanks! But it is not necessary to add the loader to services.yml.